# Invariance of a multi-vector

Tags: group-theory, clifford-algebras

I am trying to repeat the following proof of $O(2)$ invariance, but for a multivector. First, with a vector:

---

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a vector and $A$ a linear transformation:

$$
\mathbf{v}:=\pmatrix{x\\y}\implies \mathbf{v}^T =\pmatrix{x& y}
$$

Now I define a distance function as follows:

$$
f(\mathbf{v}):=x^2+y^2=\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}
$$

The linear transformations are:

$$
f(A\mathbf{v})=(A\mathbf{v})^T(A\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}^TA^TA\mathbf{v} \implies A^TA=1
$$

---

Now let us try with multi-vectors. Let $\mathbf{u}$ be a multivector of $Cl_{2,0}(\mathbb{R})$:

$$
\mathbf{u}:=xe_1+ye_2
$$

I am interested in the linear transformations that keep the geometric product $\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}=x^2+y^2$ invariant.

To define $f(\mathbf{u})$ I am already running into problems. As far as I know, there are no such things as a poly-vector valued function, only vector-valued function. Consequently, I am assuming that defining my linear transformation as $f(A\mathbf{u})=(A\mathbf{u})(A\mathbf{u})$ is inadmissible.

So is f then a function of $x,y$? Assuming this is the case, let me define it as follows:

$$
f(x,y)=x^2+y^2= \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}
$$

And with a linear transformation:

$$
\begin{align}
f(Ax,Ay)&=\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u} = (Axe_1+Aye_2)(Axe_1+Aye_2)\\
&=x^2(Ae_1)^2+xyAe_1Ae_2+xyAe_2Ae_1+y^2(Ae_2)^2
\end{align}
$$

How do I simplify this further to show that $A^TA=1$? It feels like I am missing some identities. Does $[A,e_1]=0$ and $[A,e_2]=0$. What kind of object is $A$. I doubt its a matrix; is it a multivector?

Comment: What is a multivector (or polivector)? Is it simply a vector with dimension >2 ?

Comment: @EmilioNovati sorry, I mean a multivector (clifford algebra).

Comment: It is hard to understand your train of thought. Are $x$ and $y$ real numbers? Are they vectors? What is your issue with defining $f$? Is it not $f(u)=u^2$? Also the way you present things blurs the line between defining $f$ and defining $f(Au)$, whatever it is supposed to be.

Comment: @CaptainLama $x$ and $y$ are reals, and $\mathbf{u}$ is a multivector. In the case of vectors $A$ is a matrix (in my first example a $2\times2 $ matrix) but what is $A$ in the case of multivectors? Do I apply my linear transformation $A$ to x and y, or to $\mathbf{u}$? That is: is the linear transformation of a multivector $f(\mathbf{u})\to f(A\mathbf{u})$ or to its elements $f(x,y)\to f(Ax,Ay)$?